# Is there a way to find the azure region from a runbook?

Tags: powershell, azure-runbook

I have a runbook deployed to multiple azure regions. I need to know the region in which it executes from the runbook itself. Presently I am passing the region name as a parameter while executing the runbook. But I would like to avoid it. Is there a way to find the region name from the PowerShell code itself?

Comment: What do you mean `I have a runbook running in multiple azure regions.` ? Could you explain for it? You start the runbook via some ways like powershell, webhook in different regions?

Comment: @JoyWang I have deployed same runbook to North Europe and West Europe regions. While running the runbook I am passing the region as a parameter. I don't want to pass this parameter, instead the runbook should detect the region by itself. I am expecting a commandlet like Get-CurrentRegion. I start the runbook by PowerShell as well as from the Portal in both regions.

Comment: Hi @SanthoshRamachandran were you able to find a answer for this?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find.